# angular 4 secure important informations

Tags: angular, roles

I have some important information(roles and permissions) that returns from my server side that i want to hide so no one can change their value by inspecting the page.

can any one show me how?

PS: I'm using the [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions) module to manage roles and permissions

Answer (score 1):

You should always validate this information on the server side, for every API call, to make sure you don't expose data that the user shouldn't have access to. There is no way to prevent people changing it on the client side. You can obfuscate it, but not really secure it.

JWT is a standard for digitally signing this information. But of course you still need to verify the signature on every API call to make sure the JWT token was not modified

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON Web Token (JWT). To encode secret information.

https://jwt.io/

You can use this for both Authentication and Authorisation.

If someone alters the JWT in anyway then your backend will deny the request.